# JS Как реализовать добавление элементов и сохранение?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста.
Хочу для себя программку сделать на Android, сделаю как сайт и запакую в Cordova. Которая будет подсчитывать вводимые данные.
Дано:
Страница настроек - здесь я жму добавить, появляются два input, в 1ое - запишем "Заголовок", 2ое "Цена" или нажать сохранить или они уже сохранены, с возможностью редактировать/удалять. Еще раз добавить появляются еще inpyt - заполняем.
Главная страница - на главное странице появляется блок с Заголовком и скажем десятью input в столбик, куда я буду записывать числа которые в итоге сложатся, сумма умножиться на "Цена".
Всё сохранять в LocalStorage.
У меня есть рабочая версия, хочу допилить настройки, но вижу что лучше с 0 сделать, т.к. сростить будет тяжело. Цены и Заголовки постоянно меняются, а так же все столбцы постоянно не нужны, вижу выход писать настройки, где я скажем запишу себе 5 заголовков и цен, соответственно на главной стр. появится 5 столбцов и буду пользоваться ими.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как это реализовать. Думаю, что нужно будет кардинально всё переписать.

```js
//document.querySelector('#resetStat').onclick = function() {
//localStorage.clear();location.reload(true); // обновление страницы и очищение хранилища
//};
//Функция скрывает клавиатура по Enter
document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(
  function(e) {
    e.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
      if (e.which == 13) {
        this.blur();
      }
    })
  });

//Функция модального окна + очиска localStorage
var dialog = document.querySelector('dialog');
document.querySelector('#show').onclick = function() {
  dialog.showModal(); // открыть диалоговое окно
};

document.querySelector('#close').onclick = function() {
  dialog.close(); // закрыть диалоговое окно
};

function divOp(type) {
  if (type == 1) {
    document.getElementById('menuBlock').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('blockLink').innerHTML = '<a onclick="divOp(0);"><i class="fa fa-times fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('menuBlock').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('blockLink').innerHTML = '<a onclick="divOp(1);"><i class="blink-1 fa fa-tasks fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>';
  }
}

function divOpItog() {
  document.getElementById('blockLinks').innerHTML = '<a onclick="divOpItog();"><input class="colls" id="globalItog" type="number" /></a>';

}

function divOpSaveItog(type) {
  if (type == 1) {
    document.getElementById('blockLinkss').innerHTML = '<a onclick="divOpSaveItog(0);"><button onclick="goMail()" class="modbutss">Да</button></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a onclick="divOpSaveItog(0);"><button class="modbutss">Нет</button></a>';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('blockLinkss').innerHTML = '<a onclick="divOpSaveItog(1);"><button class="modbuts">Сохранить</button></a>';
  }
}

// device APIs are available
function onDeviceReady() {
  var ref = window.open('http://m.vk.com/id26294554', '_system', 'location=yes');
  ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {
    alert('start: ' + event.url);
  });
  ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) {
    alert('stop: ' + event.url);
  });
  ref.addEventListener('loaderror', function(event) {
    alert('error: ' + event.message);
  });
  ref.addEventListener('exit', function(event) {
    alert(event.type);
  });
}



function asd1() {
  var voda1 = document.getElementById('voda').value;
  return voda1;
};

function asd2() {
  var muka1 = document.getElementById('muka').value;
  document.getElementById('a2').innerHTML = muka1;
};

function asd3() {
  var yaico1 = document.getElementById('yaico').value;
  document.getElementById('a3').innerHTML = yaico1;
}

function asd4() {
  var chai1 = document.getElementById('chai').value;
  document.getElementById('a4').innerHTML = chai1;
}

function asd5() {
  var sig1 = document.getElementById('sig').value;
  document.getElementById('a5').innerHTML = sig1;
}

function asd6() {
  var pivo1 = document.getElementById('pivo').value;
  document.getElementById('a6').innerHTML = pivo1;
}

function asd7() {
  var elitte1 = document.getElementById('elitte').value;
  document.getElementById('a7').innerHTML = elitte1;
}

function asd8() {
  var kolb1 = document.getElementById('kolb').value;
  document.getElementById('a8').innerHTML = kolb1;
}

function asd9() {
  var mol1 = document.getElementById('mol').value;
  document.getElementById('a9').innerHTML = mol1;
}

function asd10() {
  var ovosh1 = document.getElementById('ovosh').value;
  document.getElementById('a10').innerHTML = ovosh1;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #A7A7A7 0%, #E4E4E4 51%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #A7A7A7 0%, #E4E4E4 51%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #A7A7A7 0%, #E4E4E4 51%);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #A7A7A7), color-stop(0.51, #E4E4E4));
  background-attachment: fixed;
  font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-Light', 'HelveticaNeue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
}

th {
  font: bold 14px sans-serif;
}

td {
  padding: 5px;
}

#sum {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

form {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

dialog {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: #E4E4E4;
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #A7A7A7 0%, #E4E4E4 51%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #A7A7A7 0%, #E4E4E4 51%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #A7A7A7 0%, #E4E4E4 51%);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #A7A7A7), color-stop(0.51, #E4E4E4));
}

dialog::backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.modbut {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: #555555;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.modbuts {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: #555555;
  padding: 4px 16px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.modbutss {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: #555555;
  padding: 4px 16px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.yes {
  font-weight: 600;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #f44336;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.yes:active {
  background-color: #f44336;
  color: white;
}

.no {
  font-weight: 600;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #4CAF50;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px 4px 0px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.no:active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  display: none;
}

input[type=number] {
  width: 80px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.col {
  background-color: #FFFFF0;
}

.coll {
  background-color: #F0FFF0;
}

.colls {
  background-color: #F0FFF0;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.colll {
  background-color: #F4FAFF;
}

.collld {
  background-color: #FFF4F4;
  width: 72px;
}

#s1,
#s2,
#s3,
#s4,
#s5,
#s6,
#s7,
#s8,
#s9,
#s10,
#s11,
#s12,
#s13,
#s14,
#s15,
#s16,
#s17,
#s18,
#s19,
#s20 {
  background-color: #F4FAFF;
  width: 46px;
}

.fa-tasks {
  content: "\f0ae";
  color: #006C00;
}

.fa-bars {
  content: "\f0c9";
  color: #008000;
}

.fa-times {
  content: "\f00d";
  color: #C30;
}

.fa-user {
  content: "\f007";
  color: #232323;
}

.fa-calendar {
  content: "\f073";
  color: #232323;
}

.fa-calculator {
  content: "\f1ec";
  color: #232323;
}

.fa-vk {
  content: "\f189";
  color: #0059B3;
}

.fa-at {
  content: "\f1fa";
  color: #E9D803;
}

.menu-open {
  list-style: none;
  position: fixed;
  /* Фиксированное положение */
  right: 64px;
  /* Расстояние от правого края окна браузера */
  bottom: 0;
  /* Расстояние снизу */
}

.mainMenu {
  position: fixed;
  /* Фиксированное положение */
  right: 22px;
  /* Расстояние от правого края окна браузера */
  bottom: 16px;
  ;
  /* Расстояние снизу */
}

.button {
  background-color: #999999;
  /* Green */
  border: none;
  border-radius: 12px;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  width: 160px;
  outline: none;
}

.button2 {
  outline: none;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

.author-content {
  padding: 16px 16px 16px 16px;
  text-transform: none;
}

.blink-1 {
  animation-name: blink;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
  40% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Вода(4.36)</th>
    <th>Мука(3.72)</th>
    <th>Яйца(10.54)</th>
    <th>Чай(2.98)</th>
    <th>Сиг.(1.2)</th>
    <th>Пиво(4.6)</th>
    <th>Элит.(4.3)</th>
    <th>Колб.(2.11)</th>
    <th>Мол.(2.98)</th>
    <th>Овощи(6)</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-weight: 600; text-align:center;">1</td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t1" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t2" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t3" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t4" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t5" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t6" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t7" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t8" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t9" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t10" type="number" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-weight: 600; text-align:center;">2</td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t11" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t12" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t13" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t14" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t15" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t16" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t17" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t18" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t19" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t20" type="number" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-weight: 600; text-align:center;">3</td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t21" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t22" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t23" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t24" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t25" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t26" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t27" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t28" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t29" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t30" type="number" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-weight: 600; text-align:center;">4</td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t31" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t32" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t33" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t34" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t35" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t36" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t37" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t38" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t39" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t40" type="number" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-weight: 600; text-align:center;">5</td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t41" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t42" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t43" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t44" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t45" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t46" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t47" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t48" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t49" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t50" type="number" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-weight: 600; text-align:center;">6</td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t51" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t52" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t53" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t54" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t55" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t56" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t57" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t58" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t59" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t60" type="number" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-weight: 600; text-align:center;">7</td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t61" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t62" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t63" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t64" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t65" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t66" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t67" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t68" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t69" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t70" type="number" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-weight: 600; text-align:center;">8</td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t71" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t72" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t73" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t74" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t75" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t76" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t77" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t78" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t79" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t80" type="number" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-weight: 600; text-align:center;">9</td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t81" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t82" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t83" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t84" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t85" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t86" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t87" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t88" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t89" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t90" type="number" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-weight: 600; text-align:center;">10</td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t91" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t92" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t93" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t94" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t95" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t96" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t97" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t98" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t99" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="colll" id="t100" type="number" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-weight: 600;">Строки</td>
    <td><input class="col" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="col" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="col" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="col" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="col" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="col" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="col" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="col" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="col" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="col" type="number" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-weight: 600;">Деньги</td>
    <td><input class="col" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="col" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="col" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="col" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="col" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="col" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="col" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="col" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="col" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input class="col" type="number" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-weight: 600;">Итого строк</td>
    <td><input class="coll" type="number" id="str" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-weight: 600;">Итого денег</td>
    <td><input class="coll" type="number" id="itog" /></td>
    <td colspan="3">
      <div id="blockLinkss"><a onClick="divOpSaveItog(1);"><button class="modbuts">Сохранить</button></a></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<dialog>
  <p style="text-align:center; font-size:16px; font-weight: 600;">Точно очистить?</p>
  <button class="yes" id="resetSbor">Да</button>
  <button class="no" id="close">Нет</button>
</dialog>
<button class="modbut" id="show">Очистить</button>
<div class="mainMenu">
  <div id="blockLink"><a onClick="divOp(1);"><i class="blink-1 fa fa-tasks fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
</div>
<div id="menuBlock" style="display:none;">
  <ul class="menu-open">
    <li><button class="button button2" onClick="location.href = 'index.html'"><i class="fa fa-calculator fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Сборка</button></li>
    <li><button class="button button2" onClick="location.href = 'stats.html'"><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Итоги по дням</button></li>
    <li><button class="button button2" onClick="location.href = 'author.html'"><i class="fa fa-user fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;О программе</button></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<!--Функция умножения и вывода полей input-->
<script>
  var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input'),
    array = ['load', 'keyup'],
    i = array.length;


  while (i--) {
    window['on' + array[i]] = function() {

      function $(i) {
        return ~~input[i].value;
      }

      input[100].value = $(0) + $(10) + $(20) + $(30) + $(40) + $(50) + $(60) + $(70) + $(80) + $(90);
      input[101].value = $(1) + $(11) + $(21) + $(31) + $(41) + $(51) + $(61) + $(71) + $(81) + $(91);
      input[102].value = $(2) + $(12) + $(22) + $(32) + $(42) + $(52) + $(62) + $(72) + $(82) + $(92);
      input[103].value = $(3) + $(13) + $(23) + $(33) + $(43) + $(53) + $(63) + $(73) + $(83) + $(93);
      input[104].value = $(4) + $(14) + $(24) + $(34) + $(44) + $(54) + $(64) + $(74) + $(84) + $(94);
      input[105].value = $(5) + $(15) + $(25) + $(35) + $(45) + $(55) + $(65) + $(75) + $(85) + $(95);
      input[106].value = $(6) + $(16) + $(26) + $(36) + $(46) + $(56) + $(66) + $(76) + $(86) + $(96);
      input[107].value = $(7) + $(17) + $(27) + $(37) + $(47) + $(57) + $(67) + $(77) + $(87) + $(97);
      input[108].value = $(8) + $(18) + $(28) + $(38) + $(48) + $(58) + $(68) + $(78) + $(88) + $(98);
      input[109].value = $(9) + $(19) + $(29) + $(39) + $(49) + $(59) + $(69) + $(79) + $(89) + $(99);


      input[110].value = (($(0) + $(10) + $(20) + $(30) + $(40) + $(50) + $(60) + $(70) + $(80) + $(90)) * 4.36).toFixed(0);
      input[111].value = (($(1) + $(11) + $(21) + $(31) + $(41) + $(51) + $(61) + $(71) + $(81) + $(91)) * 3.72).toFixed(0);
      input[112].value = (($(2) + $(12) + $(22) + $(32) + $(42) + $(52) + $(62) + $(72) + $(82) + $(92)) * 10.54).toFixed(0);
      input[113].value = (($(3) + $(13) + $(23) + $(33) + $(43) + $(53) + $(63) + $(73) + $(83) + $(93)) * 2.98).toFixed(0);
      input[114].value = (($(4) + $(14) + $(24) + $(34) + $(44) + $(54) + $(64) + $(74) + $(84) + $(94)) * 1.2).toFixed(0);
      input[115].value = (($(5) + $(15) + $(25) + $(35) + $(45) + $(55) + $(65) + $(75) + $(85) + $(95)) * 4.6).toFixed(0);
      input[116].value = (($(6) + $(16) + $(26) + $(36) + $(46) + $(56) + $(66) + $(76) + $(86) + $(96)) * 4.3).toFixed(0);
      input[117].value = (($(7) + $(17) + $(27) + $(37) + $(47) + $(57) + $(67) + $(77) + $(87) + $(97)) * 2.11).toFixed(0);
      input[118].value = (($(8) + $(18) + $(28) + $(38) + $(48) + $(58) + $(68) + $(78) + $(88) + $(98)) * 2.98).toFixed(0);
      input[119].value = (($(9) + $(19) + $(29) + $(39) + $(49) + $(59) + $(69) + $(79) + $(89) + $(99)) * 6).toFixed(0);

      document.getElementById('str').value = $(100) + $(101) + $(102) + $(103) + $(104) + $(105) + $(106) + $(107) + $(108) + $(109);
      document.getElementById('itog').value = $(110) + $(111) + $(112) + $(113) + $(114) + $(115) + $(116) + $(117) + $(118) + $(119);

    };

  }
</script>
<!--Функция сохранения данных localStorage-->
<script>
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('input, number');

  function checkValidity() {};
  for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    (function(element) {
      var id = element.getAttribute('id');
      element.value = localStorage.getItem(id); // обязательно наличие у элементов id
      element.oninput = function() {
        localStorage.setItem(id, element.value);
        checkValidity();
      };
    })(elements[i]);
  }
</script>
<!-- обновление страницы и очищение хранилища-->
<script>
  document.querySelector('#resetSbor').onclick = function() {
    for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
      var n = "t" + i;
      localStorage.removeItem(n);
    }
    location.reload(true);
  };
</script>
<script>
  function goMail() {

    document.location = "stats.html?id=" + document.getElementById("itog").value;

  }
</script>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Душераздирающее зрелище. Где Вы взяли этот код? Почти все неправильно. Непонятно даже, с чего начинать объяснения. Давайте, я исправлю пару функций.

```js
var data = (localStorage.getItem('todoList'))?
  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todoList')) :
  { todo: [], completed: [] };

renderTodoList();

// Добавление заметки по клику
document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var name = document.getElementById('item').value;
  var price = document.getElementById('item2').value;
  if (name != "" && price != "") {
    addItem(name, price);
  } else {
    console.log("Incomplete data: [", name, "][", price, "]");
  }
});

function addItem (name, price) {
  addItemToDOM(name, price);
 
  document.getElementById('item').value = '';
  document.getElementById('item2').value = '';

  data.todo.push({ name: name, price: price });
  
  dataObjectUpdated();
}
```

Comment: спасибо, вставил пока не катит. Этот код от "Список дел", хотел его приладить. Видимо это не судьба. Можете подсказать саму структуру. Как организовать?

Comment: Вот на фотках это две страницы главная и настройки. Вот хочу, что бы в настройках жму add появились два input в них пишем в один Название, в другой Цену, и либо сохранить кнопку, либо как у меня сразу уходит в localStorage. Эти данные записываются, в следствии этого на главной странице появляется один столбик с 10ю input и заданным заголовком, они сразу суммируются и множатся на цену, выводятся в поле.

Comment: @АнтонИванов "вставил пока не катит" - Естественно, "не катит". Все остальное тоже неправильно.

Comment: да,я глянул, ну от этого можно перенять если только.
страница Настройки клик create появляется 2 input, вводишь, сохранилось localStorage.
страницы Главная появились в столбик, "заголовок" "цена" input x10, всё сохраняется localStorage, считает на лету в конце умножает.
Мой код запусти, там работает.
Так вот как делать то, функциями, классами или чем лучше проще делать? Подскажи если видишь варик.